# Bootstrap row overflows past browser view

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, row

The Bootsrtap row overflows past what I wan't it to, adding an area of scroll on the browser. How do I fix this? The site can be viewed here: [www.testing.cpukeychains.com](http://testing.cpukeychains.com)[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding 15px of margin to left and right side of the div.

Try changing (starting line 478 in styles.css):

```
.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-right: -15px;
  margin-left: -15px; }
```

to

```
.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-right: 0px;
  margin-left: -15px;
  }
```